# Executing a non ui blocking task in MPS and changing the model after task completion

Tags: mps

In [Jetbrains MPS](https://www.jetbrains.com/mps/) I want to execute a web request when the user hits a shortcut or an action from the context menu.

After successfully executing this request I want to show the user the response by manipulating the MPS model.

When I execute the web request within the UI Thread, the ui will be blocked until I get a response or the request times out.

This is of cause a bad ux experience.

How can I execute the request asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web request has to be executed in a separate thread - afaik MPS doesn't have full JDK8 support for [ForkJoinPools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) s; I use the old fashioned approach in this example.

Furthermore, you need a reference to the [ModelAccess](http://127.0.0.1:63320/node?ref=8865b7a8-5271-43d3-884c-6fd1d9cfdd34%2Fjava%3Aorg.jetbrains.mps.openapi.module%28MPS.OpenAPI%2F%29%2F%7EModelAccess) in order to change the MPS model.
The model changing code has to executed in the UI Thread.

[image: The picture show a behavior method that executes an async task and changes the model after some 2Sek.]

The `SwinUtilities.invokeAndWait` is used to execute the code within the UI thread and the `modelAccess.executeCommand` wraps the model changing code.

The `this.asyncUpdate` is a property of the concept and displayed by the concept editor.

The task in action:

```html
<iframe src='https://gfycat.com/ifr/DisfiguredAdeptAmericanbittern' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowfullscreen width='640' height='213'></iframe><p> <a href="https://gfycat.com/disfiguredadeptamericanbittern-mps">via Gfycat</a></p>
```